# 3D Nouveau drivers package

Tags: 11.10, nouveau

On 11.04, the package for providing open-source 3D acceleration on NVIDIA cards was called `libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental`. What is the Oneiric equivalent of such a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11.10 version of [`xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau) contains 3D funtionality - [Nouveau Wiki](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/UbuntuPackages)